# Problems with href in angular using bootstrap 5

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to implement tabs with boostrap in angular, but apparently href does not work to show the contents of each tab, it only shows the first one, simply to test I copied and pasted the code from the documentation in bootstrap, but for the project that I need to implement this, I tried to do it in several ways and I could not. I searched many places and found nothing. Do you have to do something else to make this component work in angular 10.

To understand me in a better way, it only shows me 'test 1', when I click on the other tabs, it does nothing.

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">test 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">test 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">test 3</div>
  </div>
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me, greetings

Answer (score 1):

You included the `angular-ui-bootstap` tag on this question, but your code sample looks like you aren't using it correctly at all. Your supplied code looks more like what you'd want to do for a non-angular site.

Check the Angular UI Boostrap docs for tabs here : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/2.0.1/#/tabs